# Python isn't recognizing installed modules on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library

I've installed Pillow using the Pip command, and it says it's installed in the system. When I run my Python3 program that imports Pillow, it returns a module not found error.
Here is the error:

```
sudo pip3 install Pillow
```

This returns:

```
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (8.1.2)
```

Then after I run my Python program which uses Pillow, I get this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pillow'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using another version of python when you run your script..

Try to run your script from the terminal and write before it (python3)

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment! After a bit more research on the PyPi page, I came to the conclusion that PIL and Pillow couldn't be run on the same machine. I hadn't realized that PIL was already installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to run it with a different python version or in a virtual environment, you can provide controls by going into the settings of your code editor.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment! After a bit more research on the PyPi page, I came to the conclusion that PIL and Pillow couldn't be run on the same machine. I hadn't realized that PIL was already installed by default.